# Sort array by one key then another key?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, sorting, nsmutablearray

basically I have an array of dictionaries and each dictionary has a `day`, `month` and `year` field.

I want to be able to sort the array by `year`, then by `month`, then by `day`. As if sorting a date.

Is this possible. This is what I have at the moment to sort by "date" as a whole:

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
[winesOfTheWeek sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
```

Is there any way to do it three times so it sorts it by year, then by month (keeping the year structure) and then by day (keeping the year and month structure).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *yearSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"year" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *monthSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"month" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *daySortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"day" ascending:NO];
[winesOfTheWeek sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:yearSortDescriptor, monthSortDescriptor, daySortDescriptor, nil]];
[daySortDescriptor release];
[monthSortDescriptor release];
[yearSortDescriptor release];
```